# How to pass Child Component state to Store without interacting with parent component using Ngxs-store?

Tags: store, angular7, state-management, ngxs

I want to pass a child component state to Store without interacting with a parent component in NGXS-Store?

previous I have pass child state to parent using EventEmmiter,  Inside parent component Html take and then parent component pass child component state to Store ......But now I need to pass child component state to directly Store not Interacting with parent component

Answer (score 0):

You dispatch an action to update state. You can do that from the child component exactly as you would in the parent component. If you're asking something else then an example of what you are trying to do would be helpful.